# How to un-link Downloads folder that was linked to User folder?

Tags: windows, windows-7, location, directory

Is there a way to set location of Downloads folder after it was set to user's default folder? There is no longer an option to set folder's location like there was prior setting it to user's folder.

[image: Picture of C:\Users folder showing that Downloads is now linked to what was a user folder]
[image: There is no longer a tab with option to set Download folder's location]

Answer (score 0):

Unlock the Downloads folder first and then there will be a "Location" tab where you will be able to set the path to wherever you'd like.